# Word document printed on MS Access report using OLE object

Tags: ms-access, ms-word, ole

For years, we have been printing Word 2003 documents that have been saved to a OLE object column using an access report.  We are using Access 2003.

For some reason when we copy a Word 2003 document and paste it into the OLE object it does not print correctly there are subtle differences with the letter spacing.

However if we use an OLE object that was copied and pasted several months ago then this prints fine.

All I can think of is it's an Office 2003 update that has caused this.

Has anybody else found this problem and any workaround solution?

Many thanks

I have created a machine without any Office Service packs on and this has got around the problem.

Comment: I would say it's generally not advisable to store documents in OLE fields. There are just too many problems with it, and it's too difficult to pull the data out reliably. The only exception to this, in my opinion, would be if you're using Jet Replication, and then that would be a good way of sharing documents at multiple locations (I've done it in the past, in fact). I'd recommend storing the documents in the file system and storing only the full path/filename in the database.

Comment: We do not store the word documents in OLE objects just for storage. We print address carriers in a specific zip code order and need to print different word documents depending on the address.

Comment: I still don't see why they need to be stored in the database, as opposed to somewhere in the file system. Perhaps there are some requirements you're failing to mention that would make it sensible.

Comment: The Access Report needs to be able to print a specific word letter depending on the address, but also maintain a strict order to qualify for mailsort postage discounts.

Comment: We have got around this by creating a virtual PC without any service packs applied to Office 2003

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is relevant to you, but it may be worth a try: [Description of the Access 2003 post-Service Pack 3 hotfix package: December 18, 2007](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/945674)

Comment: No I'm Afraid This Does Not Seem to Be Relevant